# How to send data to view from values table in django table

Tags: python, django

I am developing django app. I need to send data in my table below to the view. I used data from db to table and now i want to submit these data with remark. And i have to update some other db tables using this values too.

```
 <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
```

```
      <th scope="col">Cheque No</th>
      <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>

      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Remark</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
          {% for instance in queryset%}
          <tr>

                  <td>{{instance.cheque_no}}<input type='hidden' name='cheque_no' id="cheque_no{{instance.cheque_no}}" value='{{instance.cheque_no}}'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='{{instance.id}}'></td>
                  <td>{{instance.date_created}}<input type='hidden' name='date' value='{{instance.date_created}}'></td>
                  <td>{{instance.contributor_id}}<input type='hidden' name='contributor_id' value='{{instance.contributor_id_id}}'></td>
                  <td>{{instance.total_amount}}<input type='hidden' name='total_amount' value='{{instance.total_amount}}'></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="remark" class="vTextField form-control" maxlength="20" id="id_remark" ></td>


                  <td>
                          <div class="form-inline">
                                  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " style="height: 1.8rem; font-size: .85rem;"   role="button" value="Cancel" name='cancel'>
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " style="margin-left:10px; height: 1.8rem; font-size: .85rem;" value=" View Payment Details"  role="button" href='#'>

                      <!-- <a class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-sm"   role="button" href='/{{instance.lot_seq_no}}/deleteChequelot/'>Delete</a> -->
                                      </div></div>
                  </td>
          </tr>

          {%endfor%}

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" name="remark_all" placeholder="Remark">
<input type="submit" value="Cancel All" name="cancel_all" class='btn btn-primary'>
</form>
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: You can use request.POST.getlist, for more information refer the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60388122/get-the-values-for-selected-multiple-checkbox-in-django/60388237#60388237

Comment: Its not working i tried that. problem is i only get one value. Post request not returning all the values in the table